# Prevent VSCode auto format on save from removing final newline

Tags: visual-studio-code, autoformatting

I am using the last feature of VSCode called [formatOnSave](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_format-on-save), which is super cool.
I have one tiny problem, the formatter tends to delete the new line at the end of `json` files like `packages.json` for example.

My linter want those new lines at the end of the file, and me too.

Is there a setting or a method that allows me to tell the formatter to keep new lines at the end of files?

Related issue:

- [Provide an option to insert a final newline #1666](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1666)
- [Add "new line at end of file" option #12076](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12076)

Comment: Would be great if VSCode could link an auto-edit to which setting or extension made the edit. As it is, if you have a complex set of formatters, linters, etc. it's basically impossible to figure out the source of a random edit.

Comment: Adding a proper `.editorconfig` file in my project solved my issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This option has been added since the [release 1.8 of November 2016](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8):

> **New editor settings**
>
> - `files.insertFinalNewline` - automatically add a newline at the end of files when saving.

Comment: How to disable it, It is still inserting blank line at the end of file when I set it to false. I am using prettier too.

Comment: How to disable this? I am using prettier-eslint

Answer (score 13):

If you wish to preserve the last line in package.json and not affect other file types, add below lines to your vs code configuration.

```json
  "[json]": {
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
  }
```

This basically tells VS code to

1. Apply settings only to `json` files
2. Insert final lines at end of the file
3. Remove extra lines at the end of the file (i.e. only keep 1 empty line)

Answer (score 1):

> My linter want those new lines at the end of the file, and me too.

VSCode ESLint has [an option](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint#settings-options) called `autoFixOnSave` you could try. Depending on your workflow [ESLint CLI](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) also has a `--fix` option you could tie into a git hook.

If you're just looking for [some sensible defaults](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12076#issuecomment-340037747) here they are:

```
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
"files.insertFinalNewline": true,
"files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just changed the `prettier.endOfLine` setting from `cr` to `crlf`in VS code settings JSON
[image]